# Set logging path/file to use php://stderr

Tags: config, logs

I'm rethinking our Craft environment/workflow.  My idea is to accommodate disposable and/or multiple container (or server) environments.  As a result I want to use log aggregation apps like papertrail, logstash, etc to consolidate and investigate logging across multiple servers.  They recommend logging to php://stderr.  Is this possible?  What approach would you take to override the apps log route?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you'd need to write a plugin that has a class that extends Yii's [CLogRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRoute) and override the [processLogs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRoute#processLogs-detail) method with your own logic.  Something like this:

```
class StdErrRoute extends \CLogRoute
{
    public function processLogs($logs)
    {
        $strErr = fopen("php://stderr", "w");

        foreach($logs as $log)
        {
            fwrite($strErr, $log[0]);
        }

        fclose($strErr);
    }
```

}

Your plugin's `init()` method would register the route via `craft()->log->addRoute()`.

Comment: I've created a plugin out of this: https://github.com/nerds-and-company/loghelper